# Magento 2 Error: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.table_name' doesn't exist, while database import

Tags: magento2, database, error, import, sql

I have a fresh setup of Magento ce 2.3.2, while importing the database with sample data in fresh database and I faced this error:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento232sd.admin_passwords' doesn't exist in /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91

I am using below command for database import.

```
mysql -u root -p magento232sd < magento232sampledata.sql
```

------- Update -------

I removed the database and the done setup of Magento 2 source with sampledata and with fresh database. Then I run `bin/magento setup:install`
 command and get this error:

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...
[Progress: 1 / 941]
Required extensions check...
[Progress: 2 / 941]
Enabling Maintenance Mode...
[Progress: 3 / 941]
Installing deployment configuration...
[Progress: 4 / 941]
Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\SchemaBuilder::processReferenceKeys() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 127 and defined in /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php(127): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\SchemaBuilder->processReferenceKeys(NULL, Object(Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Schema))
#1 /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/SchemaConfig.php(66): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\SchemaBuilder->build(Object(Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Schema))
#2 /var/www/html/magento232sd/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/DeclarationInstaller.php(58): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declar in /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 137
```

I think there is something got wrong with MySQL. I dont know about that.

Comment: how you are importing data, using command line ? or direct sql

Comment: Hi @NaveedAsim Thanks for the reply. I am importing the data using the command line.

Comment: could you update you question with the commands you are running.

Comment: Hello @NaveedAsim I had updated my question with the command which I use for database import process.

Comment: First export it properly and then export it. In your `magento232sd` db, `admin_passwords` table not exists.